# Use custom Http service in Ionic 2 app

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-providers

I have some things I want to do with every HTTP request in my Ionic 2 app (v2.0.0-beta.30), so I have created my own Http class that extends angular's service. Something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class myHttp extends Http
{
    private myStuff(): void
    {
        //stuff to fo every request
    }

    public request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
    {
        this.myStuff();
        return super.request(url, options);
    }

    public get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
    {
        this.myStuff();
        return super.get(url, options);
    }
// etc.
}
```

I have stuff currently calling function on `Http`, and I don't want to have to change every thing to call `MyHttp`. I want anything making requests to not know and not care that it is actually calling `MyHttp`. It seems like there should be a way to provide `MyHttp` instead of `Http`, I'm just not sure where you would do this with an Ionic 2 app.

I tried adding it the `ionicBootstrap` function like this:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [new ProviderBuilder(Http).toClass(MyHttp)], {});
```

This just gives me the white screen of death. I also tried adding to the `@Component` decorator of `MyApp` class like this:

```
@Component({
    providers: [new ProviderBuilder(Http).toClass(MyHttp)],
    templateUrl: "build/app.html"
})
```

This gives the same white screen. I'm not sure I understand the difference, by I tried `toAlias` instead of `toClass` with the same result.

How do I tell the injector to inject `MyHttp` when anything wants to inject `Http`?

**-------- UPDATE -----------**

I finally got around the white screen of death with my attempts by also including `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in the array of providers. However, it's still injecting `Http` instead of `MyHttp` in the other services using it. I've tried each of the following:

```
{ provide: Http, useClass: MyHttp }
provide(Http, {useClass: myHttp })
new ProviderBuilder(Http).toClass(MyHttp)
```

The service that is dependent on `Http` looks like this:

```
public constructor(http: Http)
{
    //...
}
```

I put a debugger in here and I can see it is angular's `Http` instead of `MyHttp`.

**-------- UPDATE 2 -----------**

I tried to the same thing with a different class, and I do see it working. For example:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [new ProviderBuilder(MyOtherClass).toClass(MyOtherClass2)], {});
```

I see `MyOtherClass2` getting injected when it asks for `MyOtherClass`. So, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in `MyHttp` or if maybe there's some bug with `Http`. Has anyone been able to successfully do this with `Http`?

Answer (score 1):

Just like you can read [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html),  when you register a `provider` like this:

```
// bootstrap
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [DataService]);

// component
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [DataService]
})
class AppComponent { }
```

You're using a shortcut, instead of writting this:

```
// at bootstrap
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [
  provide(DataService, {useClass: DataService})
]);

// or in component
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    provide(DataService, {useClass: DataService})
  ]
})
class AppComponent { }
```

You can use that shortcut because the value of it is the same as the token. So in your case, you'd have to do it like this:

```
// at bootstrap
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [
  provide(Http, { useClass: myHttp })
]);

// or in component
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    provide(Http, {useClass: myHttp })
  ]
})
class AppComponent { }
```

Remember that if you add it in the `Component` *a new instance of that service will be created everytime that component gets loaded*. If you want to use *the same instance in the entire application* (singleton) you'd have to add it in the `ionicBootstrap` or in the **top-most** `Component` from your app.

Comment: I first tried the `provide` function like you have here, but then saw in the angular source that it is deprecated. That's why I tried using `ProviderBuilder`. I tried what you have above, and I get the white screen. I don't know if I'm just missing something else in my app or what...

Comment: Please see my updated question to see if there is any more information you can provide. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried by creating an alias for the Http service? Just like you can read [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injector-providers) you can do this by adding `[MyHttp, { provide: Http, useExisting: MyHttp }]`. That way, the same instance of your custom service will be used both for resolving the Http and the MyHttp reference.

Comment: I have tried this without success. I just added another update to my question. Things seem to work when not dealing with `Http`. I'm not sure what I would be doing wrong with `MyHttp`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Your myHttp should start with the constructor:

```
@Injectable()
export class myHttp extends Http{
...
    constructor(
        xhrBackend: XHRBackend,
        requestOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(xhrBackend, requestOptions);
    }
```

And in your app.module.ts you should import your provider as:

```
import { Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => {
        return new myHttp(backend, defaultOptions);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }

  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [new...], can you try `{ provide: Http, useClass: MyHttp }`
It will be `ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [{ provide: Http, useClass: MyHttp }], {});`

Comment: I tried this, and I get the white screen in my app. Like my comment in the other answer, I'm not sure if I'm just missing something else in my app.

Comment: Please see my updated question to see if there is any more information you can provide. Thanks.